# Image pops out container on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

On a website I'm working on I got images inside a container that need to zoom on hover. This works smooth BUT..

Whenever an image zooms in or out (when transition is kicking in) the image get's out of the container for the time of the duration.

I've adde overflow:hidden but it doesn't seem to work.

You can find the webpage in action over here: http://avdj.mtdev.be/drukwerk/

Comment: Please provide a simplyfied fiddle of the effect that troubles you, do _not_ post links to arbitrary web pages: jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in Webkit-based browsers - see [#62363](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62363).

add `opacity: 0.99;` to `wpb_content_element` to workaround this issue.